# Apply a function to multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have many dataframes where missing values are denoted by the character string `'NA'` which are not understood as missing by R.

The lengthy solution would be to apply the following function to each dataframe:

```
mydf[mydf == 'NA'] <- NA
```

**I want to apply the above function to many dataframes.**

Consider the following example:

```
set.seed(123)
A=as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('NA',1:10),10*10,T),10)))
B=as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('NA',LETTERS[1:10]),10*10,T),10))
C=as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('NA',letters[1:10]),10*10,T),10))
```

And my best try (which does not work):

```
target <- list(A, B, C)
lapply(target, function(x) x[x == 'NA'] <- NA )
```

Comment: lapply(target, function(x) x[x == 'NA'] <- NA : return(x))

Comment: And assign the results to a variable, like `target_NA <- lapply(.....`

Comment: Maybe I found a solution, but not very elegant. Is there room for improvement? `mylist=Map(function(x) ifelse(x == 'NA', NA, x), target)`
 and `for (i in 1:length(mylist)){assign(paste(i), do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist[i], unlist)))}`

Comment: `target[] <- lapply(target, function(x)replace(x, x=="NA", NA))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right. You just forgot R returns the last accessed element of a function. In your case, it was only a subset of each data frame, so set your function to return `x` and it works:

```
set.seed(123)
A = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('NA',1:10),10*10,T),10))
B = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('NA',LETTERS[1:10]),10*10,T),10))
C = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('NA',letters[1:10]),10*10,T),10))

target = list(A, B, C)
lapply(target, function(x) {
  x[x == 'NA'] <- NA
  return(x)
})
```